# How to store sum of previous indexes value in one array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here i have updated my sample code,

```
var distanceSumOfprev = 0;
          var distancesArr = [1000, 2000, 1000, 2000, 1000, 2000];
          for (var i = 1; i < distancesArr.length; i++) {
            distanceSumOfprev += distancesArr[i]
            console.log(distanceSumOfprev);
          }
```

this is what i'm getting currently

```
  distanceSumOfprev = [2000, 3000, 5000, 6000, 8000];
```

expected result

```
distanceSumOfprev = [2000, 4000, 6000, 7000, 9000];
```

Comment: *Why* are you expecting that result? Clearly the code isn't written to do it. What are the rules you want to follow to get that result?

Comment: Side note: The first entry in an array is at index 0, not index 1. You're skipping your first entry.

Comment: distanceSumOfprev += distancesArr[i - 1]  i think u need to give the index as i- 1

Comment: really ur expected result is [2000, 4000, 6000, 7000, 9000]; or [3000, 4000, 6000, 7000, 9000]; ?

Comment: @gjijo i'm expecting result like this [3000, 4000, 6000, 7000, 9000]

Comment: well, 2000 and 3000 is just off by 1000 :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a closure over the last sum and map the rest of the array.

```js
var array = [1000, 2000, 1000, 2000, 1000, 2000],
    result = array.map(function (s) {
        return function(a) {
            return s += a;
        };
    }(array.shift()));

console.log(result);
```

ES6

```js
var array = [1000, 2000, 1000, 2000, 1000, 2000],
    result = array.map((s => a => s += a)(array.shift()));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Is it correct, that you are actually passing a new callback function on each iteration of `map`, always using the first value of  the mutated `array`, as a parameter to the returned function do to `array.shift()` ? If so, i would have thought that `array` at the end of all iterations would be `[]`, but it is actually not. Turns out it will be `[2000, 1000, 2000, 1000, 2000]`. Only the first value at index `0` is missing. Or did you expect `array` not to be mutated at all ? I'm just curios, cause i never seen anyone using `map` this way. Think it's pretty creative. +1

Comment: @DavidDomain, it is just one callback, which acts as closure over `s` with the value of the last item. i mutate the array, because if not otherwise stated, it could be destroyed ...

Answer (score 4):

```js
var distancesArr = [1000, 2000, 1000, 2000, 1000, 2000];
// since we need to add each value with value at previous index, distanceSumOfprev is initialized with value corresponding to first index.
var distanceSumOfprev = distancesArr[0];
for (var i = 0; i < distancesArr.length - 1; i++) {
  //distanceSumOfprev will be having the sum of all values upto the index pointing to current loop variable.
  distanceSumOfprev += distancesArr[i + 1];
  console.log(distanceSumOfprev);
}
```

please check this

Comment: i=0 would be a bit easier... and please always add a proper description ( can be inline comments only)

Comment: @Jonas w ; Thanks for mentioning the poor documentation. I've updated my answer with some inline comments. since i am not good at describing things properly, i will be grateful towards any valuable edits on this.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is called cumsum which is short for cumulative sum.
The following code demonstrates how to do that on a copy of the original array:

```js
var distancesArr = [1000, 2000, 1000, 2000, 1000, 2000];
var cumSumArr = distancesArr.slice();
for (var i = 1; i < distancesArr.length; i++) {
    cumSumArr[i] += cumSumArr[i-1];
}
console.log(distancesArr);
console.log(cumSumArr);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you meant that the output array should start with `3000`. Then all we have to do is add one more `for` loop inside of existing loop that goes backwards `j--`

```js
var distanceSumOfprev;

var distancesArr = [1000, 2000, 1000, 2000, 1000, 2000];
for (var i = 1; i < distancesArr.length; i++) {
  distanceSumOfprev = 1000;//initialize with value at 1st index
  for(var j=i;j>0;j--){//go up to 0th index exclusive
    distanceSumOfprev += distancesArr[j]
  }            
  console.log(distanceSumOfprev);
}
```

As a result of small tweak here, you can get the desired output: **[3000*, 4000, 6000, 7000, 9000]**

Answer (score 0):

You can use `reduce()` and return new array as result.

```js
var distancesArr = [1000, 2000, 1000, 2000, 1000, 2000];

var result = distancesArr.reduce((function(c) {
  return (r, e, i) => (i == 0 ? c = e : r.push(c += e), r)
})(0), [])

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var distanceSumOfprev = 0;
var distancesArr = [1000, 2000, 1000, 2000, 1000, 2000];
for (var i = 1; i < distancesArr.length; i++) {
    distanceSumOfprev = i===1?distancesArr[i]:distancesArr[i]+distanceSumOfprev+distancesArr[0]
    console.log(distanceSumOfprev);
}
```